# Printing out an array in a method

Tags: java

I have a method that changes the values in an array declared in a class, after calling the method on an object of that class about 5 times, i want to print out the new altered array aka the array present after the method is called for the 5th time, how can i do that?

Comment: System.out.println()

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))` or `System.out.println(list)`

Comment: create a method that can return the array in the class with the array and call that method when you want to print the array

Comment: loop over the array and use `System.out.println`, or use `Arrays.toString(array)` in combination with `System.out.println`.

Comment: You can use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));` or create a for loop to iterate through your resulting array and print each element i.e. `for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){System.out.println(array[i]);}`

Comment: I am very new to coding and I do not know where and how to do all these things, i would require more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a class with an array right? Make the array private, and declare methods to read, write and display the array.

```
public class ArrayX {
    private int arr[];

    public void read() {
        // code to read array
    }

    public void write() {
        // code to write array
    }

    public void display() {
        // code to display array
    }
}
```